# Is there a way to make it view "Trigger Variables" in JOBS GitLab-CI when Implemented with parent-child mechanism,

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-api

In the sample scenario which I have tried, Below is the code snippet of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
stages:
    - ENV building

Building Openstack:
    stage: ENV building
    variables:
        RCB: ${RCB}
        SMOKE: ${SMOKE}
        APNCC: ${APNCC}
        TF_WORKING_DIR: ${OPENSTACK_TF_WORKING_DIR}
        ENV_PREFIX: ${OPENSTACK_ENV_PREFIX}
        SELENIUM_VM_PASSPHRASE: ${SELENIUM_VM_PASSPHRASE}
        SELENIUM_VM_USERNAME: ${SELENIUM_VM_USERNAME}
        UI_SMOKE_TEST: ${UI_SMOKE_TEST}
        UI_REGRESSION_TEST: ${UI_REGRESSION_TEST}
        SELENIUM_UI: ${{SELENIUM_UI}}
    script:
        echo "Hello Everyone"

Building OCI:
    stage: ENV building
    variables:
        RCB: ${RCB}
        SMOKE: ${SMOKE}
        APNCC: ${APNCC}
        TF_WORKING_DIR: ${OCI_TF_WORKING_DIR}
        ENV_PREFIX: ${OCI_ENV_PREFIX}
        #var2: $var2
        #SELENIUM_VM_PASSPHRASE: $SELENIUM_VM_PASSPHRASE
        #SELENIUM_VM_USERNAME: $SELENIUM_VM_USERNAME
    trigger:
        include:
            - test_target/oci.yml
```

In "Building Openstack" JOB the Trigger Variables passed via API(variables[key]=value) is shown to Owners and Maintainers, Similarly for the JOB "Building OCI" which in turn triggers "Child pipeline" is not showing any Trigger variables(Attached screenshot for both scenarios)

Any related information shared will be helpful

[image: 1]
[image: 2]